# After swapping Ctrl and caps in xmodmap, how can I make Ctrl work properly for multi-modifier combinations?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've swapped <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> by creating ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode 66 = Control_L
keycode 37 = Caps_Lock
clear Lock
clear Control
add Lock    = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L Control_R
```

then running `$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. Pressing the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> key works as expected, toggling <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. Pressing the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key works in general for simple shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N.</kbd>

However, when multiple modifier keys are required (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), this only works if I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key first. If I press the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key first, there is no effect.

I can reset the keyboard layout with `$ setxkbmap -layout us`, and the above shortcut will work fine. If I run `$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` again, I have the same problem.

I also find that even for single-modifier combinations, I have to hold down the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key for a split-second longer than I used to with the vanilla <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key for it to register. It's probably of the order of 0.01 seconds, but it's noticeable enough that incorrect signals are being sent one in ten times.

Also, if I swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> using `$ setxkbmap -layout us -option 'ctrl:swapcaps'`, I no longer notice the problem with the multiple modifiers. However, I still want to work out the problem with the xmodmap solution, as I'm getting a new keyboard soon, and will need to swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with a different key.

=EDIT=
I've tried another keyboard (Das Keyboard) and it seems that the second problem of having to hold down <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> for a split second longer than I did with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is probably a hardware issue with the original keyboard (an Aluminium Apple wired keyboard). However, the first problem with multiple modifiers is still present.

=EDIT=
I've tested different keystrokes in xev. Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> then pressing the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key results in `keycode 66 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol)`, as opposed to `keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L)` when 
<kbd>Alt</kbd> is not held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the above xmodmap code is *not* sufficient to swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys.

```
keycode 66 = Control_L
```

should be

```
keycode 66 = Control_L Control_L
```

to allow correct functionality when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed after another modifier. I can't find any good references to this solution but [apparently](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table) the second entry relates to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>. I'm not sure why here it also seems to apply to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>.

(Also, FWIW, other sources state there are up to eight columns, rather than the six referred to in the link.)